# C言語からPython3で作った関数を呼び出せない

Tags: c, python3

CからPython3の関数を呼び出そうとしていますがうまくコンパイルできません
pycall.cからpycall.pyのHiという関数を呼び出そうとしてしているのですが、リンクが失敗しているように見えます

どうすればいいのでしょうか?

コンパイル時のコマンド

```
clang -I`python3-config --prefix`/Headers -o pycall pycall.c
```

エラーメッセージ

```
pycall.c:4:36: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyString_FromString' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    PyObject *pycallModuleString = PyString_FromString((char*)"pycall");
                                   ^
pycall.c:4:15: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    PyObject *pycallModuleString = PyString_FromString((char*)"pycall");
              ^                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyFloat_AsDouble", referenced from:
      _main in pycall-4fd2bb.o
  "_PyImport_Import", referenced from:
      _main in pycall-4fd2bb.o
  "_PyObject_CallObject", referenced from:
      _main in pycall-4fd2bb.o
  "_PyObject_GetAttrString", referenced from:
      _main in pycall-4fd2bb.o
  "_PyString_FromString", referenced from:
      _main in pycall-4fd2bb.o
  "_Py_BuildValue", referenced from:
      _main in pycall-4fd2bb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

pycall.c

```
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    PyObject *pycallModuleString = PyString_FromString((char*)"pycall");
    PyObject *pycallModule = PyImport_Import(pycallModuleString);

    PyObject *HiFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(pycallModule, (char*)"Hi");
    PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("()");
    PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallObject(HiFunction, args);
    double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);
    printf("%f\n", result);
}
```

pycall.py

```
def Hi():
    print("Hi! I am Python3.6")
    return 3.6
```

Comment: `clang \`python3-config --includes\` -o pycall pycall.c \`python3-config --libs\`` とするのではないでしょうか。それと、Python3 では一部の API が変更になったので、`PyString_FromString((char*)"pycall")` は `PyBytes_FromString("pycall")` に変更する必要があります。

Comment: `clang \`python3-config --includes\` -o pycall pycall.c \`python3-config --libs`と実行してみましたが -lpython3.6mというライブラリが見つからないというエラーが起きてしまいます

`ld: library not found for -lpython3.6m
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: 問題が解決するかどうか分かりませんが、`python3-config --libs` を `python3-config --ldflags` に変更して試してみてもらえますか？

Comment: `--ldflags`に変えて試してみたところコンパイルは通るのですが実行時にsegmentation faultが発生してしまいます

Comment: いくつか気が付いた事がありましたので回答としてまとめます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

気付いた点は以下です。

- 最初に `Py_Initialize()` を実行(python interpreter を初期化)する
- Python 側の import path(`sys.path` 変数) に `pycall.py` があるディレクトリパスを追加
- パス名を python object に変換する場合は `PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault()` を使用

以下では `pycall.py` と `pycall` が同じディレクトリに置かれていて、そのディレクトリで `pycall` を実行するものとしています。

**pycall.c**

```
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();

  /* PYTHONPATH を使用する場合は不要 */
  PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
  PyObject* dir = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(".");
  PyList_Append(sysPath, dir);
  /* ここまで */

  PyObject *pycallModuleString = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("pycall");
  PyObject *pycallModule = PyImport_Import(pycallModuleString);

  PyObject *HiFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(pycallModule, "Hi");
  PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("()");
  PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallObject(HiFunction, args);
  double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);
  printf("%f\n", result);
}

$ ls
pycall.c pycall.py

# こちらの環境には clang がインストールされていないので gcc を使います
$ gcc $(python3-config --includes) -o pycall pycall.c $(python3-config --ldflags)
$ ./pycall
Hi! I am Python3.6
3.600000
```

`sys.path` に `.`(current directory)を追加していますが、環境変数 `PYTHONPATH` に `pycall.py` のディレクトリパスを指定して実行する場合には不要になります。例えば、以下の様に指定して実行します。

```
$ PYTHONPATH='.' ./pycall
Hi! I am Python3.6
3.600000
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> pycall.c:4:36: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyString_FromString' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>     PyObject *pycallModuleString = PyString_FromString((char*)"pycall");
> ```

C++言語と異なりC言語では宣言されていない関数の使用を認めているため、警告に留められていますが、当然ながら存在しない関数ですので呼び出すことができません。

[Python 3 への拡張モジュール移植 / オブジェクト API の変更 / str/unicode の統合](http://docs.python.jp/3/howto/cporting.html#str-unicode-unification)によると`PyString_*`系APIは`PyUnicode_*`系と`PyBytes_*`系に変更されています。
適切に修正する必要があります。